# Prove that the length of segment on tangent is constant for $y=\frac a2\ln{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}}-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Tags: calculus

Prove that the length of segment of tangent from point of tangency to the point where it cuts the y-axis is constant. 
$$y=\frac a2\ln{\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{a-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}}-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$

---

After diffrentiating:
$$y'=-\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
So tangent is $$(y-k)=-\sqrt{a^2-h^2}(x-h)$$
Point where it cuts y-axis is $(0,k+h\sqrt{a^2-h^2})$
So the length is:
$$s=\sqrt{h^2+h^2(a^2-h^2)}=h\sqrt{1+h^2-a^2}$$ which isn't constant. I did everything correctly, what should be the correct way.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy $$(t-k)=-\sqrt{a^2-h^2}(0-h)\implies t-k=h\sqrt{a^2-h^2}\implies t=k+h\sqrt{a^2-h^2}$$

Comment: You’re right, I was mistaken

Comment: I think that you lost one term in the derivation step. For me, $$y'=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{x}$$

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici, i did it once again, the constant is a

Comment: You are very welcome ! Cheers :-)

Comment: FYI: This curve is called the ["Tractrix"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractrix). (The equation given in the Wikipedia article uses a different formulation of the logarithm component; however, you can see that the derivative matches the one given by @ClaudeLeibovici.)

Comment: @Blue. Thanks for the link ! This problem was remembering me something but it was so long time ago ! But now, I remember the name. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the point of tangency be $P(x_1,y_1)$. It is easy to check that the slope of the tangent line is
$$ m=y'\big|_{x=x_1}=-\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x_1^2}}{x_1}. $$
Hence the equation of the tangent line is
$$ y-y_1=--\frac{\sqrt{a^2-x_1^2}}{x_1}(x-x_1) $$
which cuts y-axis at $Q(0,y_1+\sqrt{a^2-x_1^2})$. Now
$$ |PQ|=\sqrt{(x_1-0)^2+(y_1-(y_1+\sqrt{a^2-x_1^2}))^2}=a.$$